# Hide spinner component when Observable completed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to display a spinner within a button as soon as a certain observable starts and hide it again as soon as it ends.

After hours of researching I'm kinda lost how I could achieve it (I know there are several posts here but none of it seems to help and even the often mentioned angular-2-busy or one of it's forks doesn't really work)

So there workflow would be

I have a directive/component to which I can provide an Observable via @Input.
The directive should then show the spinner as soon as the Observable starts (or I can just use the click event).
and it should hide the spinner again when the Subscription completes.

Note: the examples below are simplified (no spinner etc. involved) but show exactly what the problem is.

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  test: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    const obs = of(true);
    this.test = obs.pipe(tap(() => console.log('tap1')), flatMap(() => {
      return this.http.get('https://httpbin.org/get');
    })
    );
  }

  demo() {
    this.test.subscribe((state: any) => console.log(state));
  }
}

export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() name: string;

  @Input()
  obs: Observable<any>;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

    if (changes.obs) {
      this.obs.pipe(map(() => console.log('component')));
    }
  }
}
```

[here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m46vhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) which illustrates what I try to accomplish and also that it currently doesn't work

When I call `subscribe` in the `hello-component` it obviously executes every piped method imediatly which is not what I want.

When I don't call `subscribe` the `pipe` operator creates a new `subscription` which obviously never gets executed.

The desired behaviour is the following output in the console.

- "tap1"
- result of the http call
- "component"

I have the feeling I'm missing something really obvious.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you possibly looking for a subject? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject observables don't allow multiple subscriptions, but Subjects do. I'm not quite sure I understand your question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure about how you want to do this, but I extended your [Stackbiltz with a solution here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r13h7k?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Main part is this:

```
showSpinner = false;
  demo() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.test.subscribe(
      tick => (console.log("event from observable")),
      error => (console.log("error from observable")),
      () => {console.log("Observable finished"); this.showSpinner=false;}
    )
  }
```

The observable has 3 event types: the "tick" will get every Observable.next, the error is called upon error, and after the last event (if the event stream has an end) will call a last, final call. You should utilize that.

**Edit**: 
you can use pipe and tap as well on the Observable definition:

```
  this.obs.pipe(
        tap(
          event => (console.log("observable event tick")),
          error => (console.log("observable error")),
          () => (console.log("observable finish"))
        )
      );
```

**Edit2**: I moved the code to the `hello.component.ts` in [this example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcb7r2?file=src/app/hello.component.ts).

**Edit3**: You cannot "listen to a listener". But, you can change your logic, to achive the wanted behaviour, see [this updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axp1nj?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Basically, you need to call the component explicitly, to inform it about the start and the end event of the spinnning event. You can view the components with `@ViewChild`, and then call their public methods directly.

Comment: I need to be able to display/hide the spinner from within `hello-component` which (currently) takes an `Observable`as input.

I have would just move your code from `demo()` inside the component it would execute immediatly.

The problem is how can I use the observable as an Input in my component and react to its completion within my component.

Comment: I moved the code to the other component, and it works just fine. Please check it out

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question/problem wrong.
Although this method works as expected my intial problem is that I don't want a click event in `hello-component` but I wanted to "react" to the completion of an observable I supply via `@Input`

Comment: ah I understand now. Updated my answer.

Comment: Your answer is not correct, judging by the docs here: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable
`"Error" and "Complete" notifications may happen only once during the Observable Execution, and there can only be either one of them.`
You're missing `this.showSpinner=false;` in the error hadler as well, otherwise, if the observable errors out, the spinner will be left still visible, indicating to a user that the request/observable hasn't completed yet, which is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Using `async` and templates can make life easier for cases like spinner :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="person$ | async as person; else loading">
    {{person.name}}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
    loading...
</ng-template>
```

[Here is the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-loading)

Comment: More info: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/